# Find centre of gravity of a column of data representing weights on a bar

Tags: excel

I'm analyzing some discrete signal information, and have two columns of data.  Column 1 is hertz, from 105 to 115.  Column 2 is a signal strength -- a number between 0 and 1.  For example:

| Hertz | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 105 | 0.0 |
| 106 | 0.2 |
| 107 | 0.1 |
| 108 | 0.4 |

I want to find the weighted centre value: that is, if these were weights, on a bar marked with Hertz, then I want to find the point at which the bar will balance.

Ideally I would like a formula in a third column that would give me the total torque at that point -- then I would just be looking for the minimum value in that column.  That would also allow me to chart the "torque" at each Hertz value.  Failing that, any formula that takes me directly to the balance point Hertz value would be good enough.

If I put in a formula on one row to find that torque at that Hertz value, it has to multiply each signal strength in column two by the difference in Hertz from that row.  E.g. the formula for the torque in row 107 is (torque from 105) + (torque from 106) + (torque from 108).  Torque from 106, for example, would be 0.2 * (106 - 107).  I can't write that formula manually, though, as I have 180 rows of data.  I suspect I need to use matrix multiplication in some way but am not seeing how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is =SUMPRODUCT((Hertz_array)*(Weight_array-Current_weight))

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$5)*($A$2:$A$5-A4))
```